# How space is compared in where condition

Tags: oracle, where

I've come across below query where it is column being compared the `space` character.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    company
WHERE   emp_name > ' ' -- space char  
AND     emp_id = 123
AND     active_flag = 'Y';
```

emp_name is VARCHAR2

Here `WHERE emp_name > ' '`, does it consider ASCII value of the space while comparing? Could someone please explain this.

Answer (score 0):

I have Oracle on local. But you can see example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d06f4/3)

```
create table a1 ( i varchar(10));

insert into a1 values('a');
insert into a1 values(' ');
insert into a1 values('v ');

select * from a1 where i <> ' '; 
select * from a1 where i = ' ';
select * from a1 where i like '% %';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would use ascii char values when comparing, and so long as it really is a space in there (it could be a no-break space which is 0xA0, or other unicode chars that look like spaces - these are called [homoglyphs](https://codebox.net/pages/homoglyph-detection)) it limits the query to returning emp_names that begin with any ascii character numerically greater than 0x20, or any string of length 2 or more, beginning with character 0x20

As to what it means, it would seem to be testing whether `emp_name` has a value, effectively. The only characters that are alphabetically less than space are control characters

Being explicit might be better:

```
ASCII(SUBSTR(emp_name, 1, 1)) BETWEEN 65 AND 122

emp_name IS NOT NULL

REGEXP_LIKE(emp_name, '[a-zA-Z ]')
```

None of these are equivalent to what your query is doing, I'm asserting that they're better because they're more self documenting as to their intent